# Visual Studio copy paste adds extra blank lines

Tags: c++

Whenever I paste something into a Visual Studio Project (C++) it adds extra blank lines. Lets say theres some code in GitHub and I want to paste it into my project.

```
const auto team_arr_prop = sdk::C_CS_PlayerResource::GetTeamProp();
const auto team_prop = team_arr_prop->m_pDataTable->m_pProps;
const auto proxy_addr = std::uintptr_t(team_prop->m_ProxyFn);
g_player_resource = *reinterpret_cast<sdk::C_CS_PlayerResource***>(proxy_addr + 0x10);
```

This is how it looks like in my Visual Studio after pasting it

```
const auto team_arr_prop = sdk::C_CS_PlayerResource::GetTeamProp();

const auto team_prop = team_arr_prop->m_pDataTable->m_pProps;

const auto proxy_addr = std::uintptr_t(team_prop->m_ProxyFn);

g_player_resource = *reinterpret_cast<sdk::C_CS_PlayerResource***>(proxy_addr + 0x10);
```

Any help? I don't want to start removing all of them one by one.

Comment: How about if you try to copy the same into some plain text editor? May be your original text contains something not visible like a carriage return. For now I can at least give you a way where you don't have to remove each extra line one by one. Try doing a replace \n\n with \n and make sure regex option during replace is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to be a problem for me when I copy-paste. What you can try is to copy it into another text program, word or notepad for example, and then from there copy it into VS

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by "spaces" you mean the blank lines.

When copying code from a GitHub page viewed in the Edge browser, one way to get rid of those blank lines is to click on the "RAW" button and then copy the code from the resulting page.

[image: Screenshot of GitHub showing the RAW button]

From a quick experiment it appears that the extra blank lines are not added if you view the GitHub page in the Chrome browser and copy the code from there.

**Update:**  The above is based on Visual Studio 2017 as installed and configured on my systems (which is *mostly* as it comes out of the box).  Your mileage may vary.

I haven't experimented enough to form an opinion but the observed behaviour *might* be affected by [ClangFormat](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/03/13/clangformat-support-in-visual-studio-2017-15-7-preview-1/) or [EditorConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2017) or by the particular line ending used by the file being edited.

Visual Studio 2017 supports five different line endings...

[image: screenshot of Visual Studio Line Endings dialog]

Comment: oh ima download Chrome, i just started using Microsoft edge, god damn i knew this browser ir garbage, thank you